# Pattern matches by row name with multiple columns in multiple files

Tags: bash, unix, join, awk

I have two files, one with a full list of gene names and three others with partial lists of gene names. I want to match these files all into one. All the partial files are different number of rows but have **3000 columns**, all representing different cells. I have been trying to join these files completely but when I use awk only one column is kept.

mergedAll.txt

```
GENE
SOX2
BRCA1
BRCA2
RHO
```

ultimatecontrolMed.txt

```
GENE     CELL1   CELL2   CELL3
SOX2     30      152     2000
BRCA2    400     234     73
RHO      12      2       0
```

My Desired output would be

```
GENE     CELL1   CELL2   CELL3
SOX2     30      152     2000
BRCA1    0       0       0
BRCA2    400     234     73
RHO      12      2       0
```

I run:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{k[$1];next}{b[$1]=$0;k[$1]}
END{for(x in k)
      if ( x== "GENE" )
         printf"%s %s\n",x,b[x]
      else
         printf"%s  %d\n",x,b[x]
}' mergedAll.txt ultimatecontrolMed.txt > test.txt
```

And I get:

```
GENE CELL1 CELL 2 CELL3
SOX2 2000
BRCA1 0
BRCA2 73
RHO 0
```

For some reason it will keep the last column of counts but not any of the other lines, and keep all the cell names. I don't have any experience with awk so this has been a major challenge for me overall and would love it if someone could offer a better solution.

Comment: `a[$1] = $2` there is no `$2` in the first file.

Comment: You never use the `a` array, what is that statement for?

Comment: so what should I write instead? I am not familiar at all with awk. I thought I had to use it to assign the value of the first file, do I only need to have the k[$1]?

Comment: I don't know, what are you trying to do there?

Comment: Why are you using `awk` for this? It looks like you could just use the `join` command to do what you want.

Comment: I am unsure how to use join if it is not sorted or has the same number of rows

Comment: The real problem is that you're trying to print `b[x]` with `%d` formatting. That just prints a single integer, so it ignores all the other integers in the value. Why don't you just use `%s` to get the whole value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0; next} 
               {print (a[$1]?a[$1]:($1 FS 0 FS 0 FS 0))}' file2 file1 | 
  column -t

GENE   CELL1  CELL2  CELL3
SOX2   30     152    2000
BRCA1  0      0      0
BRCA2  400    234    73
RHO    12     2      0
```

final pipe to `column` is for pretty printing.  Note the order of the files.

Not to hard code the number of columns you can try this alternative

```
$ awk 'NR==1   {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) missing=missing FS 0}  
       NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0; next} 
               {print (a[$1]?a[$1]:($1 missing))}' file2 file1
```

Comment: amazing! Thank you very much!

edit: actually it worked to merge them but genes that didnt exist originally in the file2 only would have the three 0's. there are 3k cells in my actual data

Comment: Thank you so so so much! I was struggling with this for days haha

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($1 in a){print;delete a[$1];next} END{for(i in a){print i,"0 0 0"}}' mergedAll.txt  ultimatecontrolMed.txt
```

Comment: A good answer should explain what was wrong and how you fixed it, not just dump code.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I usually do :). I am on the way to write it, let me post it and get back to you then

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're printing `b[x]` with `%d` format. That's for printing a single integer, so it will ignore all the other integers in `b[x]`. Change

```
     printf"%s  %d\n",x,b[x]
```

to:

```
    if (b[x]) {
        printf "%s\t%s\n", x, b[x]
    } else {
        printf "%s" x;
        for (i = 0; i < 3000; i++) printf "\t0"
        print ""
    }
```

so that it will print the entire value. If there's no corresponding value, it will print zeroes.

Replace `3000` with the appropriate number of cells. If you don't want to hard-code it, you can get it from `NF-1` when `FNR == 1 && FNR != NR` (the first line of the second file).

Comment: This solution had that same problem as karakfa, it allowed for the files to be merged, but I only will have three 0's when I need 3000 in my actual data set. I am looking for a way to not have to manually write the 0 three thousand times. This is appreciated though!

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {printf "\t0"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
join -a 1 -a 2 -e 0 -o 0 2.{2..4}  mergedAll.txt ultimatecontrolMed.txt
```

`2.{2..4}` prints a list of output fields and can easily adapted to any number of fields.

As you mention three input files, it would be possible to pipe the result of a first join into a second one

```
join .... file1 file2 | join ... file3
```

`join` needs sorted input. That may be a killer argument for this solution.